# Android Manifest duplicate registration for activity

Tags: android, android-studio, android-manifest

We decided to make an intro/welcome screen to our app. The activity called Welcome Activity needs to be launched when user goes to the application for the first time. All other times Main Activity needs to be launched. That's how I've done it in Android Manifest:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
package="com.google.android.gms.samples.vision.ocrreader"
android:installLocation="auto">

<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />

<application
    android:name=".OcrApplication"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:fullBackupContent="false"
    android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/icon"
    android:label="Ingredient analysis"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.vision.DEPENDENCIES"
        android:value="ocr" />
    <activity android:name=".WelcomeActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustPan"
        android:exported="true"
        >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".OcrCaptureActivity"
        android:label="Read Text" />
    <activity android:name=".ListResult" />
    <activity android:name=".AllIngredients" />
    <activity android:name=".IngredientDescription" />
    <activity android:name=".Instruction" />
    <activity android:name=".WelcomeActivity">  </activity>
</application>
```

However, there is an error - Duplicate registration for activity in this line:

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Duplicate registration for activity` happens when you register same Activity twice.

In your case you have registered `WelcomeActivity` twice. Once immediately after `<application>` tag and once at the very end.

Remove following re-registration line from end of your mainfest (before `</application>` tag)

`<activity android:name=".WelcomeActivity">  </activity>`

Answer (score 0):

this problem usually occurs while there will be same name `<activity` tags multiple time.

In you code, found that, you used WelcomeActivity twice.

remove the `<activity android:name=".WelcomeActivity">  </activity>` (see at the last portion of your code, you will find that. just remove the line).